# Set property Map<Object, Class<?>> into spring.xml

Tags: java, spring

In my class I have this setter

```
public void setSomehing(Map<Object, Class<?>>  beans){
...
}
```

`Object` is some bean, and `Class` is it's interface.
I try more combination but I always got

> `cvc-complex-type.2.3:` Element 'map' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

Some of combination is:

```
<bean id="rmiServerBeanFactory" class="org.infobip.spring.remoting.server.StandaloneCompositeRmiServerBeanFactory">
        <property name="something">
               <map>
                 <entry key-ref="myBean" value="org.mypackage.MyBeanInterface"/>
             </map>
        </property>
      </bean>
```

Please help. how to set this in spring.xml?

Answer (score 1):

This error message is due to a syntax error in the XML. In this example, you only want the map element to have a single entry child right? Look for stray characters between the opening and closing map tags. Try retyping all then content of that element again as you intended it.

See a similar problem and solution [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/485875/Spring/cvc-complex-type-Element-beans). You only need to look at the first and last post.

Answer (score 0):

hm maybe this example in my application helps you:

namespace util is

```
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" 

   <property name="something">
        <util:map map-class="java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap">
            <entry key="a" value="b"/>
        </util:map>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of doing this, but one of the more compact ones is as follows:

```
<map value-type="java.lang.Class">
    <entry key-ref="myBean" 
           value="org.mypackage.MyBeanInterface"/>
</map>
```

(Tested on Spring 3.0.)

Answer (score 0):

Your XML formatting and syntax is wrong somewhere. What it really means (the Sinn) is that the ... element is allowed to contain sub-elements, but not naked text ("content type is element-only") and the stray plus sign is naked text.